# Change local-only Wi-Fi hotspot's SSID and password in Android Oreo 8.x

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo, hotspot

In my Android application I'm using the following code snippet:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void turnOnHotspot(){
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    
    manager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback(){
    
        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
            super.onStarted(reservation);
            Log.d(TAG, "Wifi Hotspot is on now");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStopped: ");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
            super.onFailed(reason);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailed: ");
        }
    },new Handler());
}
```

This piece of code creates a hotspot named something like "AndroidShare_1234". For a project of mine I need to be able to set a password and  SSID to this hotspot.  However, I can't find a way to do this.

Note that the `setWifiApEnabled`  is not supported anymore in Android O.  This is how it's done in older versions of Android. However, I still need to programmatically make a Wi-Fi hotspot with an SSID and a password. I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks in advance!

**For who cares...:**

For a school project I made a locker that unlocks whenever it can connect to a wireless network with certain credentials hence the need of setting a hotspot programmatically.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but have you considered using Bluetooth to either perform the authentication or to publish the network SSID?

Comment: Note that according to the documentation of ``startLocalOnlyHotspot``, the hotspot may be shared between several apps. This indicates that modifying the SSID is unlikely to be officially supported.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Visionwriter nope :(

Comment: @Markinson did you found the solution yet ?

Answer (score 17):

I have only a partial solution to the problem. Hopefully, it will be sufficient for the application you are designing.

**The SSID and the password are hard-coded by the android system when you start the Hotspot**. By looking over at the AOSP code, I see that the same hotspot can be shared by multiple applications. The configuration for this hotspot(class name is `WifiConfiguration`) is also shared with all the requesting applications. This configuration is passed back to the application in the callback `onStarted(LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation)`. You can get the `WifiConfiguration` by calling `reservation.getWifiConfiguration()`. You will get all the information you need from the `WifiConfiguration` object. So you can **read** the Pre-Shared Key and the access point name. But I don't think you can change them



FYI, The relevant code that sets up the wifi configuration (including the hard-coded SSID and WPA2-PSK key) is done by the following piece of code

```
  /**
   * Generate a temporary WPA2 based configuration for use by the local only hotspot.
   * This config is not persisted and will not be stored by the WifiApConfigStore.
   */
   public static WifiConfiguration generateLocalOnlyHotspotConfig(Context context) {
       WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
       config.SSID = context.getResources().getString(
              R.string.wifi_localhotspot_configure_ssid_default) + "_"
                      + getRandomIntForDefaultSsid();
       config.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA2_PSK);
       config.networkId = WifiConfiguration.LOCAL_ONLY_NETWORK_ID;
       String randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       // first 12 chars from xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
       config.preSharedKey = randomUUID.substring(0, 8) + randomUUID.substring(9, 13);
       return config;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answe......`context.getResources().getString(
              R.string.wifi_localhotspot_configure_ssid_default) + "_"
                      + getRandomIntForDefaultSsid();` can give us the format please..

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: It is not possible to change the SSID

Comment: is there any workaround solution for that....I want to create hotspot name with some specific name sir..

Comment: @Gowthamam, As far as I know, there isnt a way to set a specific name.

Comment: Still same not effect on name !

Comment: For our use case we also need to set ssid and password programitically. Any solution appreciated.