# How to change WiFi Hotspot name and also perform a Wifi Scan in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have been trying to search a way to changes Wifi Hostspot name of android device using flutter. I also wanted to get a list of available wifi nearby using flutter. I have just started learning flutter and i dont have much knowledge to write plugins for it from scratch. Is there any easier way to perform above two things?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd-party [wifi package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi) might help you out with listing available networks. It supports Android, but not iOS.

For the hotspot situation, you can check out this (unpublished, only on github) [package: wifi_iot](https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter). That one also mostly supports Android for most functions. You would need to test it yourself and extract which functions you need, because you can't get it through https://pub.dartlang.org/

Comment: i tired using wifi_iot package to get accespoint turn on but it gives a lot errors and doesnt gets on on Andorid 8+. I just need the access point to get on with particular name and dont need any internet connectivity. I found this article saying that it cant be done on android 8 : https://medium.com/@jean.creuzedeschatelliers/how-to-activate-the-mobile-hotspot-on-android-programmatically-or-not-5931e44097e3  so is there anything you know about as apps like share it still work which turn on the hotspot.

Comment: I guess it's definitely doable in Java/Kt, so you would need to implement it like that first and then follow a flutter guide to create a binding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I searched for it a lot and came to know that they have depreciated the earlier functions used or the same in android 8 and 9. They did introduce Local Wifi Hotspot but it doesn't allows us to change ssid name either according to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700717/change-wifi-hotspots-ssid-and-password-in-android-oreo-8-x