# how to get SSID and Password for hotspot (kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, wifimanager, hotspot, ssid

**I'm trying to create a hotspot using `startLocalOnlyHotspot()`**

*my code:*

```
var ssid = "null"
var password = "null"

wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(object : LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() {
                override fun onStarted(reservation: LocalOnlyHotspotReservation) {
                    super.onStarted(reservation)
                    if(reservation.wifiConfiguration != null) {
                        ssid = reservation.wifiConfiguration!!.SSID
                        password = reservation.wifiConfiguration!!.preSharedKey
                    }

                }

            }, Handler())
```

I trying to get SSID and password from `startLocalOnlyHotspot()`

I put default value for them both as `"null"` as string just to test
because I'm using this value to generate QR-code so I need string

and this value never changes however it creates a hotspot

what did I miss??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem and found some answer in this post: [Change WiFi hotspot's SSID and password in Android Oreo 8.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700717/change-wifi-hotspots-ssid-and-password-in-android-oreo-8-x).However it seems that you cannot change the SSID or password with Local Only Hotspot.
Hope you find a solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I will use p2p